# Kotlin delegate property causes a preview rendering error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-delegate

I have created a custom property dedicated to holding properties of the view that require invalidate() call for one of my projects:

```
class InvalidatingProperty<T>(private var _value: T) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: View, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return _value
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: View, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        _value = value
        thisRef.invalidate()
    }
}
```

In another project, I wanted to reuse some of my previous work, so i copied the views and their dependencies, including the InvalidatingProperty, to a new project. In the new project though, using the InvalidatingProperty causes the preview render to fail with a following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.jvm.internal.MutablePropertyReference1Impl.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at com.gradesimulator.views.SummaryView.<clinit>(SummaryView.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:416)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:331)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:348)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:678)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The source projcet (where the preview does work) and the target project, both have the same android version - 4.0.1, use the same version of kotlin and kotlin gradle plugin - 1.4.0

Also, the important fact is that on the emulator or the real device the views work completly fine

I've already tried the Invalidate Chaches/Restart, and tried to downgrade kotlin as i found some issues regarding the 1.4.0 version that caused similar exception.

EDIT: Upon further inspection, sometimes a different exception seems to occur:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gradesimulator.views.SummaryView
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:416)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:331)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:348)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:678)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Compressed SummaryView Code:

```
@Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate", "unused", "PropertyName")
class SummaryView : View {

companion object {

    private const val TAG = "SummaryView"

    //primary circle
    const val DEFAULT_PRIMARY_CIRCLE_RADIUS_SCALE: Float = 1F

    const val DEFAULT_PRIMARY_CIRCLE_DISPLACEMENT: Float = 0.3F

    //secondary circle
    const val DEFAULT_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_RADIUS_SCALE: Float = 1F

    const val DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_DELAY: Long = 100

    const val DEFAULT_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_DISPLACEMENT: Float = 0.2F

    //both circles
    const val DEFAULT_CIRCLES_SHADOW_RADIUS: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_CIRCLES_SHADOW_DISPLACEMENT: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_CIRCLES_ANIMATION_DURATION: Long = 600

    //bigAverage
    const val DEFAULT_BIG_AVERAGE_SHADOW_DISPLACEMENT_X: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_BIG_AVERAGE_SHADOW_DISPLACEMENT_Y: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_BIG_AVERAGE_SHADOW_RADIUS: Float = 0F

    //smallAverage

    const val DEFAULT_SMALL_AVERAGE_SHADOW_DISPLACEMENT_X: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_SMALL_AVERAGE_SHADOW_DISPLACEMENT_Y: Float = 0F

    const val DEFAULT_SMALL_AVERAGE_SHADOW_RADIUS: Float = 0F

    //average
    const val DEFAULT_AVERAGE_MARGIN: Float = 0.4F

    //progressArc
    const val DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_PROGRESS_ARC_ANIMATION_DURATION: Long = 1200

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_MARGIN: Float = 0.2F

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_WIDTH: Float = 0.1F

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_START_ANGLE: Float = 10F

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_VALUE: Float = 0.96F

    //progressArcDot
    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_DOT_RADIUS: Float = 1.5F

    //progressArcContent
    const val PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_DEFAULT_MARGIN = 0.4F

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_TEXT = "Of the success!"

    const val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_INTERLINE = 0.1F

    const val PARTICLE_DATA_REGEX = ";"
}

//primaryCircle
val DEFAULT_PRIMARY_CIRCLE_COLOR: Int = Color.GRAY

//SecondaryCircle
val DEFAULT_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_COLOR: Int = Color.DKGRAY

//Both circles
val DEFAULT_CIRCLES_SHADOW_COLOR: Int = Color.BLACK

//bigAverage
val DEFAULT_BIG_AVERAGE_SHADOW_COLOR: Int = Color.BLACK

//smallAverage
val DEFAULT_SMALL_AVERAGE_SHADOW_COLOR: Int = Color.BLACK

//Averages
val DEFAULT_AVERAGE_COLOR: Int = Color.WHITE

//progressArc
val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_COLOR: Int = Color.WHITE

//progressArcDot
val PROGRESS_ARC_DOT_DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE

//progressArcContent
val DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_COLOR = Color.WHITE

//particles
val DEFAULT_PARTICLE_COLOR = Color.DKGRAY

//View
var animateInCirclesAnimationDuration = DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_CIRCLES_ANIMATION_DURATION

var animateInProgressArcAnimationDuration = DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_PROGRESS_ARC_ANIMATION_DURATION

var animateInSecondaryCircleDelay = DEFAULT_ANIMATE_IN_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_DELAY

//Circles
private val primaryCirclePaint: Paint = Paint()

private val secondaryCirclePaint: Paint = Paint()

var primaryCircleCenterDisplacement: Float by InvalidatingProperty(
    DEFAULT_PRIMARY_CIRCLE_DISPLACEMENT
)

var secondaryCircleCenterDisplacement: Float by InvalidatingProperty(
    DEFAULT_SECONDARY_CIRCLE_DISPLACEMENT
)

var primaryCircleColor: Int
    set(value) {
        primaryCirclePaint.color = value
        invalidate()
    }
    get() = primaryCirclePaint.color

var secondaryCircleColor: Int
    set(value) {
        secondaryCirclePaint.color = value
        invalidate()
    }
    get() = secondaryCirclePaint.color

var primaryCircleRadiusSCale: Float by InvalidatingProperty(1F)

var secondaryCircleRadiusScale: Float by InvalidatingProperty(1F)

fun setCirclesShadow(radius: Float, dx: Float, dy: Float, color: Int) {
    primaryCirclePaint.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color)
    secondaryCirclePaint.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color)
}

fun setBigAverageShadow(radius: Float, dx: Float, dy: Float, color: Int) =
    bigAveragePaint.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color)

fun setSmallAverageShadow(radius: Float, dx: Float, dy: Float, color: Int) =
    smallAveragePaint.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color)

//Big Average
private val bigAveragePaint: TextPaint = TextPaint()

var bigAverageText: String by InvalidatingProperty("")

//SmallAverage
private val smallAveragePaint: TextPaint = TextPaint()

var smallAverageText: String by InvalidatingProperty("")

//Both averages
var averageMargin: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_AVERAGE_MARGIN)

var averageColor: Int
    get() = bigAveragePaint.color
    set(value) {
        bigAveragePaint.color = value
        smallAveragePaint.color = value
        invalidate()
    }

//Progress Arc
private val progressArcPaint: Paint = Paint()

var progressArcMargin: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_MARGIN)

var progressArcStrokeWidth: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_WIDTH)

var progressArcStartAngle: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_START_ANGLE)

var progressArcValue: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_VALUE)

private val progressArcRectF: RectF = RectF()

//ProgressArcDot
private val progressArcDotPaint = Paint()

var progressArcDotRadius: Float by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_DOT_RADIUS)

//Progress Arc Content
private val progressArcContentPaint: TextPaint = TextPaint()

val progressArcContentMargin: Float by InvalidatingProperty(PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_DEFAULT_MARGIN)

var progressArcContentColor: Int
    set(value) {
        progressArcContentPaint.color = value
        invalidate()
    }
    get() = progressArcContentPaint.color

var progressArcContentText: String by InvalidatingProperty(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_TEXT)

var progressArcContentTextInterline: Float by InvalidatingProperty(
    DEFAULT_PROGRESS_ARC_CONTENT_INTERLINE
)

//Particles
private val particlePaint: Paint = Paint()

private val particles: ParticleSet =
    ParticleSet(this)

var particlesColor: Int
    set(value) {
        particlePaint.color = value
        invalidate()
    }
    get() = particlePaint.color

//Util
private val textBoundsRect: Rect = Rect()
private val textBoundsRect2: Rect = Rect()


constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
    initView(null)
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    initView(attrs)
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {
    initView(attrs)
}

constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyleAttr: Int,
    defStyleRes: Int
) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    initView(attrs)
}

private fun initView(attrs: AttributeSet?) { //code }

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) { // code }
```

Comment: Why doesn't your delegate implement `ReadWriteProperty<View, T>`?

Comment: @Nicolas [According to official reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html), as long as it provides  implementations for the getValue and setValue it doesn't have to

Comment: Can you share the code for SummaryView? Because your delegate works for me.

Comment: I have edited the question to include some SummaryView code. Just in case i want to emphasize again - its only the android studio layout editor where the delegate property causes an exception.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that it's only causing a problem in the editor.
In my setup it seems to only be happening when using kotlin 1.4.0, while 1.3.72 doesn't produce either of those errors.

Comment: I suspect it might be a problem with the IDE so [i have created an isssue on google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165312270). The project whrere the rendering works is actually migrated from kotlin 1.3.7 so that might be actually why it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the kotlin-reflect version from 1.4.0 to 1.3.72 has worked for me:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72"
```

Comment: What was the version you were previously using? Did you mean you downgraded it? Doesn't sound like a good solution because it may affect some other places in the app.

Comment: Yes, I've downgraded it from 1.4.0, I will edit the answer include this. While certainly not perfect, this was the only solution I could find for the time being. I've also reported this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165312270).

Comment: Thanks for the Google issue tracker link 

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "-Xno-optimized-callable-references" in the module with your view. Helped me.

```
android {
...
    kotlinOptions {
...
        freeCompilerArgs = [
                "-Xno-optimized-callable-references"
        ]
    }
}
```